# Windows audio stops working when playing games through a receiver

Tags: audio, graphics-card, hdmi

I have a Windows 8 desktop with two nVidia GeForce 680 GTX video cards. When I connect the video card to a TV via HDMI the audio through HDMI works fine all the time.

When I connect the video card to a Sony receiver (STR DN-1050) via HDMI the audio seems to work fine and the receiver shows PCM audio however when I start to play any games all audio (including iTunes in the background) stops working and will not come back without restarting the computer.

If I connect to the receiver using optical I can consistently get 2 channel audio just fine but it doesn't support surround sound.

I suspect that DirectX is involved, perhaps trying to change the audio format on the transport to something else (ie. DTX) and failing thus leaving the audio in a borked state. I ran dxdiag and it indicates no issues. The driver is the nVidida driver, 358.91 (359.00 seems to have an issue on my system in Fallout 4).

In the control panel for the HDMI audio device I can see the supported formats but I have no way to test them (for the optical device I can).

How can I further diagnose these audio problems and (hopefully) resolve them.

Comment: Not an answer, but [AudioSwitcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audioswitcher/) can easily flip between outputs on the fly - might enable you to at least experiment without rebooting every time

Comment: Oops - better link - http://audioswit.ch/er

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly due to HDCP (HD copyright protection) and DRM. Sony has been particularly forceful in restricting copying or pass-through of streams, going so far as to [install a rootkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal).

**If** that is the cause of your issue, you might try [using an HDMI splitter](http://www.howtogeek.com/208917/htg-explains-how-hdcp-breaks-your-hdtv-and-how-to-fix-it/) to [bypass this erroneous restriction](http://forum.ibroadcastnetwork.org/showthread.php/1511-HDMI-Splitter-Removes-HDCP). Splitters are available for ~US$25.

Comment: The nVidia drivers report my TV as supporting HDCP.